# Svelte not generating public or dist folder with vite

Tags: build, svelte, vite, sveltekit, production

I'm extremely confused about why when I run `npm run buid` it says it's compiling everything but it does not generate a public or dist folder. I'm able to develop and preview everything fine with `npm run dev`. Everything online says to just run this command and it'll generate the files.

```
 npm run build      

> svlt-drag@0.0.1 build
> vite build


vite v4.1.4 building SSR bundle for production...
✓ 51 modules transformed.
5:06:18 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] ssr compile done.
package         files     time     avg
svlt-drag           4   31.5ms   7.9ms
@sveltejs/kit       1   13.1ms  13.1ms

vite v4.1.4 building for production...
✓ 42 modules transformed.
5:06:19 PM [vite-plugin-svelte] dom compile done.
package     files     time     avg
svlt-drag       5   62.0ms  12.4ms
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/version.json                                 0.03 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/vite-manifest.json                                2.73 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/assets/_layout.ed6dad0e.css        9.13 kB │ gzip: 2.48 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/2.6b2094ff.js               0.08 kB │ gzip: 0.10 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/1.4e7307ad.js               0.08 kB │ gzip: 0.10 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/0.8c6f33b6.js               0.09 kB │ gzip: 0.10 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/_layout.svelte.733b317a.js   0.54 kB │ gzip: 0.36 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/error.svelte.8dbce21f.js     0.98 kB │ gzip: 0.57 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/singletons.ccd991f9.js      2.65 kB │ gzip: 1.38 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/app.c122a3c5.js              5.61 kB │ gzip: 2.25 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/_page.svelte.68b65054.js     7.21 kB │ gzip: 3.02 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/chunks/index.33c9bb49.js           7.72 kB │ gzip: 3.18 kB
.svelte-kit/output/client/_app/immutable/entry/start.2b8c1d1f.js           23.16 kB │ gzip: 9.22 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/vite-manifest.json                           1.43 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/_layout.ad198ccc.css  15.05 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/internal.js                                  0.19 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.svelte.js              0.25 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/fallbacks/error.svelte.js            0.83 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_page.svelte.js                2.54 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index.js                              3.68 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js                           5.09 kB
.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js                                    85.12 kB

Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-auto
  Could not detect a supported production environment. See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters to learn how to configure your app to run on the platform of your choosing
  ✔ done
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem a while ago.

Make sure that in `svelte.config.js` you have the line `import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';`

(I had adapter-auto)

Answer (score 2):

Like [Giovanni Abbatepaolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21982109/giovanni-abbatepaolo) said on his answer, you need to use the static adapter and for that you need to first install it running `npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-static`. This adapter is used when you want to prerender your entire site as a collection of static files, which will be outputted to your `dist` folder.

Here is the documentation explaining it https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the output, by default the built files are in `.svelte-kit/output`. The [adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters) may have settings to specify another output directly if you want.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get the entire adapter thing in Svelte, I'm used to working with React or Ember where it just compiles down to a basic html, css, and js file and you copy and paste those to your server and then it's live and you don't need to configure anything. It seems like Svelte assumes you're doing server side rendering? I don't want that, I just want a client side app with a hash in the URL for routes like #/people/steve.

Comment: SvelteKit does not do hashes. You'll want the [static adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static) and should read up on adapters in general.

Comment: Looks like it can: https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router

Comment: They shouldn't be using a "static page adapter" for single page applications - that's very confusing and doesn't make sense at all. Everything is rendered dynamically client side and nothing is static or pre-rendered.

Comment: It depends on the config, everything can potentially be prerendered. You also seem to misunderstand; SvelteKit is not Svelte, it is an application framework that includes a router, what you linked to is a package that is supposed to be used with just Svelte that was created before SvelteKit existed. When using SvelteKit you should not use a separate router, it will not be compatible with most things SvelteKit provides.

Comment: Didn't know that. Another front end app framework that's over-engineered and complicated and doesn't do what you need or expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

My svelte.config.js have only these options,

import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default {
// Consult https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-preprocess
// for more information about prepro`enter code here`cessors
preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
}

*How to solve the adapter issue for this case? :)*

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35765619)